# Ubuntu MAAS DHCP working DNS Not working

Tags: networking, server, dns, maas, dhcp

I setup Ubuntu 14.04 MAAS on one server. I setup interface to manage DHCP and DNS via the Cluster interface. DHCP is working. But, DNS is not!

When I try to add another node, it is doing PXE boot, getting IP address from the cluster controller, and booting up...But, it is not connected to internet - "ping google.com" does not work.

I have two interfaces on MAAS server. One interface connected to our organization network. And, another interface for managing private network - all the nodes for the cluster. The latter interface is where I have my own DHCP Server.

My DHCPD.Conf
 option domain-name-servers <>;
I even tried setting it to 
 option domain-name-servers <>;

Any suggestions on how I can fix the above?

Thanks

Comment: Following error appears: failed [3/6] (00-maas-03-install-lldpd, 99-maas-01-wait-for-lldpd, 99-maas-02-capture-lldp) - I referenced http://ideasnet.wordpress.com/category/ubuntu-14-04lts-cloud-computing-server-edition/ and changed /etc/squid-deb-proxy/allowed-networks-src.acl to include private network...still problem....any suggestions?

Comment: I remember something about making your DNS server have an upstream source, so that it knows where to go when its clients ask for things it doesn't know.  I have now given you more information than I have.

Comment: Set upstream DNS

Open http://<maas-server-ip>/MAAS/settings/ in a browser. Look for "Upstream DNS used to resolve domains not managed by this MAAS" and set the DNS to something like 8.8.8.8 [whatever your upstream dns server is]